# Tomcat7 installed on ubuntu but not responding

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04

I installed tomcat7 manually on my ubuntu 14.04 machine using this website: http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-tomcat-7-ubuntu-14-04/#manual (the manual way).

It is installed correctly but when trying to open the default page using http://server-ip:8080 it is not opening and giving me: This webpage is not available

My log file has no errors:

```
Jan 14, 2015 11:35:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 14, 2015 11:35:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 14, 2015 11:35:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jan 14, 2015 11:35:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 14, 2015 11:35:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 14, 2015 11:35:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 14, 2015 11:35:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages$
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 713 ms
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/docs
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/docs has finished in 533 ms
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/host-manager
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/host-manager has finished in 104 ms
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/manager
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/manager has finished in 59 ms
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/manager has finished in 59 ms
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/ROOT
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/ROOT has finished in 56 ms
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/examples
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/examples has finished in 424 ms
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 14, 2015 11:42:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1262 ms
```

Comment: wrong ip or firewall blocking 8080?

Comment: @Stefan ip is right, how to check if firewall is blocking 8080?

Comment: @Stefan I stopped the firewall but still not working

Comment: Log into your server with ssh. Install a simple text based browser, like "links" (#sudo apt-get install links) and connect to tomcat "locally": #links http://localhost:8080. Are you able to see the page?